# Toggle Series within a Chart using VBA

Tags: excel, excel-charts, vba

Good Morning people,

I am looking to toggle a chart series using VBA and user-form to select specific series, I've had success with a line chart. However when I try to use a bar chart, it does not seem to update the data, only the legend.

The VBA code I am using is:

Module:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ChartContent() 'Excel VBA process to select the chart and show the userform.
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Select 
ufChart.Show 

End Sub
```

Userform:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdApply_Click()
    Dim iSres As Integer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ActiveChart
        .HasLegend = False
        .HasLegend = True
        For iSres = .SeriesCollection.Count To 1 Step -1
            If ListBox1.Selected(iSres - 1) Then
                .SeriesCollection(iSres).Border.LineStyle = xlAutomatic
                .SeriesCollection(iSres).MarkerStyle = xlAutomatic
            Else
                .SeriesCollection(iSres).Border.LineStyle = xlNone
                .SeriesCollection(iSres).MarkerStyle = xlNone
                .Legend.LegendEntries(iSres).Delete
            End If
        Next
        .Deselect
    End With
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
  Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim iSres As Integer

    With ActiveChart
        For iSres = 1 To .SeriesCollection.Count
            ListBox1.AddItem .SeriesCollection(iSres).Name
            ListBox1.Selected(ListBox1.ListCount - 1) = Not (.SeriesCollection(iSres).Border.LineStyle = xlNone)
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Would anyone have any suggestions on why this may be occurring and possible solutions so I could apply this VBA to a bar chart, I am not quite sure as to why its not updating with a bar chart.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by replacing some code, if a bar chart is required use this:

```
 With ActiveChart
        .HasLegend = False
        .HasLegend = True
        For iSres = .SeriesCollection.Count To 1 Step -1
            If ListBox1.Selected(iSres - 1) Then
                .SeriesCollection(iSres).fill.Visible = msoTrue
                .SeriesCollection(iSres).MarkerStyle = xlAutomatic
            Else
                .SeriesCollection(iSres).fill.Visible = msoFalse
                .SeriesCollection(iSres).MarkerStyle = xlNone
                .Legend.LegendEntries(iSres).Delete
            End If
        Next
        .Deselect
    End With
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Excel 2013 or 2016, you can easily filter the series without VBA. Select the chart, and click on the lowest of the three "skittles" beside the chart. A filter fly-out appears with checkboxes for each series in the chart. Uncheck a box and click Apply to hide the series, then check it to make it appear again.

[image: Filtering series in a chart]